# Ajax success JSON loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JS function that uses ajax to filter options in a sub navigation/filter menu.

It makes the calls correctly and receives the JSON response from the server, however it won't loop through the results.

It is only displaying the last result in the JSON response.

The ajax script:

```
function updateVenues(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/venue-search/ajax/",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts, get_param: 'id'},
      success: function(records){
        $.each(records, function(idx, record){
         $("#searchResults").html('<a href="/venue-preview/' + record.id + '" class="various fancybox.ajax">' + record.title + "</a>");
       });
      }
    });
  }
```

A typical response from the server

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"Wedding Venue 1","main_image":"wedding-venue-1.jpg"},
{"id":"2","title":"Wedding Venue 2","main_image":"wedding-venue-2.jpg"},
{"id":"3","title":"Wedding Venue 3","main_image":"wedding-venue-3.jpg"}
]
```

Could anyone shed some light on why it isn't looping?

Comment: You aren't adding to `#searchResults` you are overwriting the contents of it every time you go through the loop.  Try using `.append()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `.html` it's overwriting the entire contents with the new value, which is why you only get the last one displayed.  You need to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
function updateVenues(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/venue-search/ajax/",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts, get_param: 'id'},
      success: function(records){
        //clear out any previous results first
        $("#searchResults").empty();
        $.each(records, function(idx, record){
         //now append each one
         $("#searchResults").append('<a href="/venue-preview/' + record.id + '" class="various fancybox.ajax">' + record.title + "</a>");
       });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! Your answer is near enough identical to that of Shail, however you also include the "clearance" of the previous results. Worked perfectly. I shall mark it as the answer as soon as I can (9 minutes!). Thanks again!

Comment: I prefer `$("#searchResults").empty();` over `$("#searchResults").html('');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function updateVenues(opts){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/venue-search/ajax/",
  dataType : 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: {filterOpts: opts, get_param: 'id'},
  success: function(records){
    $.each(records, function(idx, record){
     $("#searchResults").append('<a href="/venue-preview/' + record.id + '" class="various fancybox.ajax">' + record.title + "</a>");
   });
  }
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$("#searchResults").append('<a href="/venue-preview/' + record.id + '" class="various fancybox.ajax">' + record.title + "</a>");
```

Otherwise you overwrite your "#searchResults") in each loop.